# Fill the Tableview with Array of Dictionary and separating by section

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, tableview

How I can fill tableview from array of dictionary and separate it by section

I receiving data from Firebase and it might be sometimes null sometimes
2 or 3 items. The type of data is array of dictionary [[String:Int]]
If it has an item it can be for example:

```
var selectedVariation:[["ice": 20$, "cold": 30$], ["no Choco": 0$, "with Choco": 40$]]
```

In this case I should separate the tableview in nonamed 2 section.
First section should contain ["ice": 20$, "cold": 30$] and second ["no Choco": 0$, "with Choco": 40$]

With code below I can just fill the tableview without sections and should manually write numberOfRows

```
var selectedVariation: [[String:Int]]?  
var keysArray: [String] = []
var valueArray: [Int] = []


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return selectedVariation?.count ?? 0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return 4
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VariationCell", for: indexPath) as! VariationTableViewCell
    for section in selectedVariation! {
    
    for (key, value) in section.sorted(by: {$0.1 < $1.1}) {        
         keysArray.append(key)
         valueArray.append(value)
    }
 
}
cell.variationName.text = keysArray[indexPath.row]
cell.variationPrice.text = "+" + String(valueArray[indexPath.row]) 
return cell
}
```

And bonus would be, if I can make a checkmark just one item in each section:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to map the dictionaries to custom structs, but if you want to keep this data model the table view data source methods are

```
var selectedVariation = [["ice": 20, "cold": 30], ["no Choco": 0, "with Choco": 40]]

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return selectedVariation.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    selectedVariation[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VariationCell", for: indexPath) as! VariationTableViewCell
    let section = selectedVariation[indexPath.section]
    let key = section.keys.sorted()[indexPath.row]
    let value = section[key]!
    cell.variationName.text = key
    cell.variationPrice.text = "+" + String(value)
    return cell
}
```

Note: `func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int` is Swift 2